# Subscribe function (event.currentTarget.activeElement.id) is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, publish-subscribe, jquery-events

I am trying to call a subscribe function written by using publish. But the event captured has id blank. Following is my code

```
$.subscribe('onCmbNomineeSalutationComplete', function(event, data) {
    onCmbNomineeSalutationChange(data, 'complete', event);
});
```

And I am trying to call it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.publish('onCmbNomineeSalutationComplete');
});
```

The sub function gets called, but when I check it with debugger the `event.currentTarget.activeElement.id` is blank.

Kindly help me to identify what is going wrong here, and how I can  get the id/name of the element by this method.

Also it would be of great help if someone could explain pub/sub in simple way.